# How to get records based on status or recent updated timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following Vehicle table with given records.

```
Create Table Vehicle (Vehicle_Type varchar(50),Car_Number number,Car_Type varchar(10),Car_Status char(1),Car_Repaired_Date Date);
Insert into Vehicle(Vehicle_Type,Car_Number,Car_Type,Car_Status,Car_Repaired_Date)values('CAR',123456,'SUV','Y','16-MAR-20 06.49.05');
Insert into Vehicle(Vehicle_Type,Car_Number,Car_Type,Car_Status,Car_Repaired_Date)values('CAR',234567,'SUV','N','16-MAR-20 06.49.05');
Insert into Vehicle(Vehicle_Type,Car_Number,Car_Type,Car_Status,Car_Repaired_Date)values('CAR',334567,'SEDAN','N','16-MAR-20 06.49.05');
Insert into Vehicle(Vehicle_Type,Car_Number,Car_Type,Car_Status,Car_Repaired_Date)values('CAR',4567890,'SEDAN','N','14-MAR-20 06.49.05');
commit;
```

I am trying get records for Vehicle_Type='CAR' where CAR_STATUS='Y' with distinct CAR_TYPE.If any of the CAR_TYPE's CAR_STATUS='N' then get the recently updated CAR for that CAR_TYPE.

**INPUT:**

[image: INPUT]

**Expected OUTPUT;**

[image: Output]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it SQL Server or Oracle you are asking about? (They are different products with somewhat different language syntax)

Comment: Removed the sql-server tag

Comment: Is this a homework question? If yes, then please see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This is not an homework question.I just converted my original question with easily understanding  schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*,
             row_number() over (partition by car_type
                                order by car_status desc,   -- 'Y' before 'N'
                                         car_repaired_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from vehicle v
      where vehicle_type = 'CAR'
     ) v
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per `car_type` (based on the `partition by` clause).  That row is either the most recent row with a `'Y'` or if there are no `'Y'`s, then then most recent with an `'N'`.

Comment: How can we rewrite if the car_status has more than 'Y','N'.For Example IT also have flag 'A' with ' A' as priority?

Comment: You can use a `case` expression in the `order by`:  `order by case car_status when 'A' then 1 when 'Y' then 2 when 'N' then 3 else 4 end . . .`.